# How to export raster into ascii without losing the statistics?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, statistics, ascii

I had a problem in Mike Urban with a difference between a DEM (Digital Elevation Model) and a 2D overflood model and the support group requested me to remove the difference because the problems were at the edges of the area.

Then I found an inspiration by: [ArcGis--how to lower a DEM's Z value along a line](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75577/arcgis-how-to-lower-a-dems-z-value-along-a-line)

I made a polyline in Arcgis and afterwards converted it to raster and reclassify the file(to remove the NoData) and at last I subtracted the area from the original DEM to edit the height by the Minus Tool.

Afterwards I tried to convert the raster file to ASCII by the converting tool, but when I open the file in MIKE Urban (GIS-based urban modeling system for water distribution systems and wastewater collection systems) the statistics (max, mean etc.) were missing.

Is there another way to convert the file without losing data?